# question about compress header

Tags: c++

from this site   there is header "compress.h"

```
http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/examples/compress/compress.html
```

i am using visual c++ 2010  and also boost library and    am interested if there is similary header of compress.h?
thanks

Comment: What are you talking about :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the header given on that page.

The web page seems to describe code that the author provides and at first glance it is standard and should work in Visual Studio